# How to include border around cells when using IPython.display of Pandas table in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In Python 3.4, the cells were easy to see because they had a black border around them. In Python 3.5, the this border has been replaced with a more subtle white/grey shading, which makes the cells blend together visually. I want to add a black border like Python 3.4 used to use. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add something like this to your `.jupyter\custom\custom.css` file:

```
.rendered_html table, .rendered_html th, .rendered_html tr, .rendered_html td {
  border: 1px  black solid !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

You can read more about customizing jupyter notebook [here](http://sherifsoliman.com/2016/01/11/theming-ipython-jupyter-notebook/).

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!