# Can you add a border to a cell in Jupyter Notebook which remains after output is rendered?

Tags: python, html, css, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Here is an example of a basic notebook:

[image: example]

When working on a cell I know that particular cell would have a temporary border around it to highlight that this particular cell has been selected - in my example the "Introduction" cell is highlighted. This is not the border I am referring to in my question.

**I was curious to know if it is possible to add a border around any cell (particularly markdown) which remains after the output is rendered.** It's a bit like bordering one or more cells in Microsoft Excel. This is just for styling purposes.

**Does anyone have any ideas?** Any tips are welcome :)

*Here is the text written in each cell for reference:*

```html
# <span style="color:red">Example</span>
```

```html
<u> **Introduction:** </u>  
This notebook is just an example.
```

```py
# Here is some code:

num = [1, 2, 3]
for i in num:
    num = i + 1
    print(num)
```

```html
<span style="color:blue">***The End***</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041452/how-to-include-border-around-cells-when-using-ipython-display-of-pandas-table-in) could help you.

Get access to your Jupyter custom.css file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook)

and add the following:

```
.rendered_html table, .rendered_html th, .rendered_html tr, .rendered_html td {
  border: 1px  red solid !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

If you want to personalize more, have a look at [Jupyter Themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)